# Sort thru a file with int and string values in numerical order with python

Tags: python

I have a text file which has the following values:

```
username:password - number of daily visits: 15
username:password - number of daily visits: 482
username:password - number of daily visits: 4823
```

I want to filter the file in numerical order from highest to lowest, so the highest number of visitas would be on the top of the file, and the lowest on the end of the file, I want to do that but keep all the string values, so it would look like that:

```
username:password - number of daily visits: 4823
username:password - number of daily visits: 482
username:password - number of daily visits: 15
```

I managed to do that but the string values wouldn't be maintained, so it would be just:

```
4823
482
15
```

I really have no idea, I'm a beginner still learning.

Comment: post the code you used to do this much and we'll advise what to change

Comment: What part of the problem are you struggling with? Reading the file? Extracting the number from the strings? Sorting a collection? Sorting one collection based on the values of some specific key? Writing the result back to a file? Please share code of what you've already tried and be specific about the issue - SO is here to help solve your problem, but not to write your code for you. [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: what kind of file is it? please elaborate on your question more that we can help you.

Comment: Good evening. First : does your file have "user:password - number of daily visits:" in every line ? If so, you can first split each line with '-' and then with ':'. It will allow you to isolate the numerical value. Then you'll be able to sort them easily. I hope it helps !

Comment: I know Stack Overflow ain't to do your coding, I just haven't found any solution or tip from the internet, and I don't have a teacher since I'm learning from YouTube videos, so all I had left is to ask on here. Sorry if it looked like I just wanted people to write my code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you always have a number in the end of the line, you could use `sorted` with a custom key:

```
with open('file.txt') as f, open('file2.txt', 'w') as f2:
    f2.writelines(sorted(f.readlines(),
                         key=lambda s: int(s.rsplit(' ')[-1].strip()),
                         reverse=True))
```

input `file.txt`:

```
username:password - number of daily visits: 15
username:password - number of daily visits: 482
username:password - number of daily visits: 4823
```

output `file2.txt`:

```
username:password - number of daily visits: 4823
username:password - number of daily visits: 482
username:password - number of daily visits: 15
```

##### how it works

- read the content of the file as a list of lines: `f.readlines()`
- extract the list digit by splitting the line on the last space, getting the last item (`[-1]`), ensuring there is no trailing newline (`strip()`) and converting to int.
- sort the lines with `sorted`, using the above extracted number as key, use the reverse order to have larger numbers first
- write the lines in the new file with `writelines`

Comment: that's a fairly complex solution for a beginner

Comment: @Kurt do you think so?  It's only using standard methods

Comment: While I do approve of this solution, breaking it down into smaller chunks and explaining along the way what's going on might make it more digestible for a newcomer.

Comment: @Chris I added the detail of the main steps